# Cannot setCurrentItem(0) on CirclePageIndicator

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

If you have this code in Activity `onCreate()`:

```
mViewPager = new ViewPager(this, null);
mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(this);
mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
mCirclePageIndicator.setViewPager(mViewPager);
mCirclePageIndicator.setOnPageChangeListener(onPageChangeListener);
```

Then launch an AsyncTask and want to change the current page in it's `onPostExecute()` with the page 0, then it won't work. It works with any other page != 0, but with 0 it just retains the current position.

```
mCirclePageIndicator.setCurrentItem(0);
```

If anybody comes up with an idea, feel free to share. Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Workaround:**

First set another page as the current page, then set to page 0. Yes, I know, it's retarded, but I still haven't found an explication as to why it isn't working in the first place. I've tried posting it in a `Handler`, even with a delay, but nothing. Nada.

```
mCirclePageIndicator.setCurrentItem(1);
mCirclePageIndicator.setCurrentItem(0);
```

Comment: I would assume its because the indicator assumes its at page 0 to start with.

Comment: After adding new items in the adapter and also changing the position on screen ? Don't think so...

Comment: Really cool you got this working.  I've been trying to figure it out for a while now.  Would be interesting to understand the mechanics a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

i found out that the CirclePageIndicator.java has a bug, it did not want to fill the selected page circle when i first start my **Fragment**, but when i just touch my **ViewPager**, every thing is ok ... the bug was there :

```
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
    mCurrentPage = position;
    mPageOffset = positionOffset; // error here
    invalidate();

    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels);
    }
}
```

the **positionOffset** returned **Nan** when i initialized my views in **onCreate**, which caused **onDraw()** not to draw the filling of my selected circle

the solution is to check for the **positionOffset** value before assigning it, like :

```
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
    mCurrentPage = position;
    mPageOffset = (positionOffset > 0) ? positionOffset : 0;
    invalidate();

    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is setting `indicator.onPageSelected(0)` after calling `setCurrentItem(0)`. Taking a look at the code, what that does is set the `mSnapPage` to the position, which is otherwise not done.

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    if (mSnap || mScrollState == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
        mCurrentPage = position;
        mSnapPage = position;
        invalidate();
    }

    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onPageSelected(position);
    }
```

This is terribly hacky though. I hope they fix it :/